# Transform a long format date to a short format

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

The small program I am using (below) gives a `Date0` value in a "long" form:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["A",  -33.415424]
         ],
         columns = [
             "Country",
             "Time0"
         ]
    )
df = df.set_index("Country", drop = True)
d = datetime.strptime("2020-01-22", '%Y-%m-%d')
df['d'] = d
df['Date0'] = df['d'] +  pd.to_timedelta(df['Time0'], unit='d')
```

```
              Time0             d                        Date0
Country             
A        -33.415424     2020-01-22  2019-12-19 14:01:47.366400
```

How can I get `Date0` to be "only" `2019-12-19`?

Surely a basic question, but I'm sorry to say that I am completely lost in formatting dates in Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
df['Date0'] = df['Date0'].dt.date
```

Output:

```
           Time0         d        Date0
  Country           
     A   -33.415424 2020-01-22  2019-12-19
```